# git confusion about committing and pulling

Tags: git

when I use the command **git push** from a terminal opened in the directory of my clone of a repository, I get a message that it's all up to date, yet in the pending changes in **gitk** in the same directory I see that nothing is committed and everything is a pending change. also when I try to pull in another library that I use, because I made small changes it tells me that it can't pull while there are pending changes, how do I remove the changes, delete the files and **pull**?

Comment: You might have changed files which are not added to a commit. Did you `git add .` and `git commit -m "your commit message"` to create a commit?

Comment: doesn't push just send the files to the repository and handle all the merging?

Comment: git add . 
is a bad idea. As well as git commit -m is .

Comment: Trying to use Git without having ever read a few chapters of the Git book is like trying to drive across a large city without having ever attended a few hours of driving school.

Answer (score 0):

Pending changes imply you haven't committed all the changes in your repository. So you'll have to follow these steps :

```
git add . //This add all the changes to the staging area.
git commit -m "your message" //-m will help you identify the commit later on
git pull <repo>
git push <repo> <branch>
```

Always remember you can pull/push only after you have committed all the changes.

Comment: Nope, <repo> means your repository name and <branch> means your branch name, you mention it if you have multiple repos/branches

Comment: but doesn't git know about them from the directory I'm commiting from + the branch that I have set to be on previously, using "git branch"

Comment: Your current branch is set by `git checkout <branch>`. `git branch <branch>`, will only create the branch, not navigate to it. In any case, the repo and branch can be ignored if you only have one remote repo/ one branch.

Comment: must I pull before I push? no one has made changes except me since my initial checkout

Comment: In that case you don't have to. But it is always a good practice to pull before you push, especially if you are collaborating with others.

Comment: ok one last thing - I made the commit with my message, if I just write git push now, what will be the consequences - that is, if I don't add the repo and branch

Comment: Since you have only one repository and one branch, `git push` will push the current branch to your remote repo.

Comment: rather than running 'git add .' run 'git status' and then 'git add <each> <file> <like> <this>' so that you never push/add wrong files. More so - 'git add .' will only add current directory - files that are some place else will not go to staging area. git commit without -m flag will open your default editor and let you produce a high quality commit message easily.